# OpenCL region growing

Tags: opencl

i'm trying to make a region growing segmentation for my project in OpenCL, can anyone please help me writng the code

the algorithm is as follows:

1. seed the first pixel(seed) manually
2. get the value of the seed
3. compare it with its 4-neighbors or 8-neighbors(i dont know which is better)
4. if the neighbors have the same value then they are in region
5. compare these neighbors with there other neighbors and so on until it finds a boundary, then stop

thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented an OpenCL version of this algorithm in the FAST framework for 2D and 3D. See here: https://github.com/smistad/FAST/tree/master/source/FAST/Algorithms/SeededRegionGrowing

In our GPU segmentation review article you can find an explanation of the implementation as well as a performance analysis: http://www.medicalimageanalysisjournal.com/article/S1361-8415(14)00181-9/fulltext#s0075